# When IGBT is off what is the leakage current between collector and emiter?

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, igbt

When ı saw datasheet of IGBT, there are two terms of about leakage current between collecter and emiter. But ı can not be sure is these terms are about leakage current?

These terms are Ices and BVces. My questions are listed below.

1- Is Ices leakage current between collector end emiter ?

2- IF Ices is leakage current, is there any connection between BVces and Ices? 
For examples BVces = Ices*Rces. Is this true ? If this equation is true, Can ı say Rces is isolation resistor when IGBT is off?

Datasheet link : https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_igbts/littelfuse_discrete_igbts_xpt_ixy_8n90c3_datasheet.pdf.pdf

Comment: link to the datasheet

Comment: Okey. I was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ices is the leakage current between collector and emitter at the specified Vces of 900V. It is different at 25C (10uA) and 150C (150uA) junction temperatures.

BVces is the breakdown voltage between collector and emitter. 'Breakdown' is defined as the voltage at which the leakage current rises to 250uA, at 25C.

Please don't put these voltages and currents into 'Ohm's Law' ratios. It doesn't really help. There is no 'resistor' in the device, and any calculated 'resistances' will be far from constant, and vary wildly with voltage and temperature. That is, a resistor model of this type of device is not generally useful as a 'current source' model for the leakage current.

Comment: The "s" at the end of "Ices" and "BVces" indicates it is with the base shorted (in this case to emitter). An "o" would indicate it was open eg "ICEo".